# Convert GradientDrawable to Bitmap

Tags: android, drawable, android-custom-view, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I have the following gradient (generated dynamically):

```
    GradientDrawable dynamicDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
    dynamicDrawable.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT);
    dynamicDrawable.setUseLevel(false);
    int colors[] = new int[3];
    colors[0] = Color.parseColor("#711234");
    colors[1] = Color.parseColor("#269869");
    colors[2] = Color.parseColor("#269869");
    dynamicDrawable.setColors(colors);
```

and I want to set that drawable in a view using onDraw method.

When I want to assign a Drawable to a bitmap I use the casting (BitmapDrawable), but in that case is not possible due the gradientDrawable cannot be cast to BitmapDrawable.

Any idea about how I solve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve? some image maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a mutable bitmap using `Bitmap.createBitmap()`
- Create a `Canvas` based on the bitmap using `new Canvas(bitmap)`
- Then call `draw(canvas)` on your `GradientDrawable`

Comment: Thanks for response, really useful.

Comment: how does it work? I mean then we simply use the `bitmap` whereas I'm drawing a `canvas` on `gradient`. It's kinda confusing. Can you help?

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the solution from your response. I paste the code for someone could need it:

```
private Bitmap createDynamicGradient(String color) {
    int colors[] = new int[3];
    colors[0] = Color.parseColor(color);
    colors[1] = Color.parseColor("#123456");
    colors[2] = Color.parseColor("#123456");

    LinearGradient gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400, Color.RED, Color.TRANSPARENT, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setDither(true);
    p.setShader(gradient);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawRect(new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()), p);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: what is use of colors array, color string ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code mention in: [Android: Convert Drawable to Bitmap](https://msol.io/blog/android/android-convert-drawable-to-bitmap/)

```
public Bitmap convertToBitmap(Drawable drawable, int widthPixels, int heightPixels) {
    Bitmap mutableBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthPixels, heightPixels, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, widthPixels, heightPixels);
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return mutableBitmap;
}
```